# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1-a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)}{1-2a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)+a^{2}}=\frac{n}{1-a^{n}}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation-method

How do prove this relation?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1-a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)}{1-2a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)+a^{2}}=\frac{n}{1-a^{n}}  \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } a\in(-1,1)$$

Comment: It looks like the denominator is the square of the numerator.  But don't just post questions in a vacuum.  Give some context, show some effort, share some thoughts.  We're not here to help you cheat on your homework.

Comment: @B.Goddard I don't think the denominator is the square of the numerator (look at the coefficient of $a^2$).

Comment: Hint: if you consider both sides as functions of $a$, you can read this as the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of the RHS, over the reals. There are simple and systematic ways to compute this decomposition, and it's especially easy when there are no multiple poles.

Comment: Hint: write the sum as $\Re\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-az^k}$ with $z:=e^{2\pi i/n}$, then show the $\frac{1}{1-az^k}$ are the $n$ roots of $(aw)^n-(w-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's start with a function like this:
$$f\left(x\right)=x^n-1\Rightarrow f'\left(x\right)=nx^{n-1}$$
$$x^n-1=0\Rightarrow \left[x_k=e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{n}}\right]_{k=1,2,3,..n}$$
From partial fraction we have:
$$\frac{1}{f\left(x\right)}=\frac{1}{x^n-1}=\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{A_k}{x-x_k}$$

$$\boxed{A_k=\frac{1}{f'\left(x_k\right)}=\frac{1}{n\left(e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}\right)^{n-1}}=\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}{n}}$$

$$\frac{n}{x^n-1}=\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}{x-e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}$$
$$\frac{n}{x^n-1}=\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{e^{-\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}x-1}$$
$$\frac{n}{x^n-1}=\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x\cos \left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-xi\sin \left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-1}$$
Now we take real part from both side:
$$\boxed{\Re \frac{1}{a+bi}=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}}$$

$$\frac{n}{x^n-1}=\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{x\cos \left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-1}{x^2-2x\cos \left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)+1}$$
So the proof is done.